# Getting error using factor() function inside a reactive expression in the shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am developing a shiny app for regression analysis. I get an error when I want to change some variables to factor using the `factor()` function.

I want the user to select the variables he\she wants to change to factor from a `selectInoput()` and use a reactive function to feed the results to a new dataframe but the result is very weird! :(

I put a simplified version of what I do here.

Spent a day and could find the solution. Would appreciate your help.

```
x <- c( 1:5 )
y <- c( 10:14)

df <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y
)

library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

    
    titlePanel(""),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
           selectInput(inputId = "str", label = "which variables should be changed to factors",choices = names(df), multiple = T)
        ),
        
        

        mainPanel(
          verbatimTextOutput("output")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  df_2 <- reactive({
    df[ , input$str ] <- factor(df[ , input$str ])
  })
  
  output$output <- renderPrint({
    str( df_2() )
  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code only needs minor modification in `server`.

```
x <- c( 1:5 )
y <- c( 10:14)

df <- data.frame(
  x = x,
  y = y
)

library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel(""),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "vars", label = "which variables should be changed to factors",choices = names(df), multiple = T)
    ),

    
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("output")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  selected_vars <- reactive(input$vars)
  
  df_2 <- reactive({
    df[selected_vars()] <- lapply(df[selected_vars()], as.factor)
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$output <- renderPrint({
    str(df_2())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```